# Black screen on Unity3d startup on Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I start Unity3d (Version 5.6.0) it shows this black (dark gray) screen and nothing's happening.

I reinstalled it and still the same.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a conflict between a 32/64-bit Editor and OS? If that's not the case, another version of Unity might work.
https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

Comment: I fixed this bug by installing Version 5.6.5 (I wanted 5.6.0). Hopefully I can work it out with this version. Thanks.